# How to load a new scene you create in current scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I made a 3Dworld with Unity and I want save my world in a menu. I save my world with:

`EditorApplication.SaveScene("Assets/Scene/name.unity",true);`

And I add my new Scene to my build setting with:

```
var original = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
    var newSettings = new EditorBuildSettingsScene[original.Length + 1];
    System.Array.Copy(original, newSettings, original.Length);
    var sceneToAdd = new EditorBuildSettingsScene("Assets/Scene/name.unity", true);
    newSettings[newSettings.Length - 1] = sceneToAdd;
    EditorBuildSettings.scenes = newSettings;
```

When I load my new scene without closing the game:

```
Application.LoadLevel("name");
```

I have this error :

```
Level 'name' (-1) couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings.
To add a level to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...
```

When I look in my build settings, my new scene is added and checked.
If I rebuild the game I can load my new scene but I don't want rebuild the game to load a new level when I just saved it.

How I can refresh my build settings without closing the game?
Or how I can save my new scene more simply?

Edit : I found a alternative, I create my scene first , I add it in build settings and I erase it in the game when I save with the same name.

Comment: Try changing the order of scenes in build settings.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code before `Application.LoadLevel("name");` to add it to your Build Settings:

```
 var original = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
 var newSettings = new EditorBuildSettingsScene[original.Length + 1];
 System.Array.Copy(original, newSettings, original.Length);
 var sceneToAdd = new EditorBuildSettingsScene("Assets/Path/To/Scene/name.unity", false);
 newSettings[newSettings.Length - 1] = sceneToAdd;
 EditorBuildSettings.scenes = newSettings;
```